# HTMLAgilityPack new selection in for each loop

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, html-parsing, html-agility-pack

I have this html code

```
<div class="featuredTorrent">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <div class="torrentName">
                                <a href="/sub/2/0/" class="Movies" title="Movies > Divx/Xvid"></a>
                                <span class="nameComment">2</span>                                    <h3 class="org"><a href="/torrent/394358/Batman-Dark-Knight-Returns-2012-Part-1-DVDRip-Xvid-AC3-Legend-Rg/" class="org">Batman.Dark.Knight.Returns.2012.Part.1.DVDRip.Xvid.AC3.Legend-Rg</a></h3>
                                <div class="clr"></div>
                            </div>
                            <span class="seed">1541</span>
                            <span class="leech">139</span>
                            <span class="size">803.67 MB</span>
                            <div class="user"><h4 class="vip"><a href="/user/scene4all/">scene4all</a> <sup title="Reputation Points">*5061</sup></h4></div>
                            <div class="clr"></div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="odd">
                            <div class="torrentName">
                                <a href="/sub/2/0/" class="Movies" title="Movies > Divx/Xvid"></a>
                                <h3 class="org"><a href="/torrent/394330/Batman-The-Dark-Knight-Returns-Part-1-2012-FRENCH-DVDRip-XviD-SLaP/" class="org">Batman.The.Dark.Knight.Returns.Part 1.2012.FRENCH.DVDRip.XviD-SLaP </a></h3>
                                <div class="clr"></div>
                            </div>
                            <span class="seed">1257</span>
                            <span class="leech">94</span>
                            <span class="size">699.04 MB</span>
                            <div class="user"><h4 class="uploader"><a href="/user/maximersk/">maximersk</a> <sup title="Reputation Points">*5003</sup></h4></div>
                            <div class="clr"></div>
                        </li>
```

I want to retrieve the "h3 class=org" and the span with class seed, leech and size.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    url = "http://1337x.org/search/2012/0/"
    document = webGet.Load(url)
    Dim a, b As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNodeCollection
    Dim s As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode
    Dim name, dUrl, seed, peer, size As String
    a = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='torrentName']/h3[@class='org']")
    For Each div As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode In a
        name = div.InnerText

    Next
    b = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='featuredTorrent']/ul/li")
    For Each div As HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode In b
        s = div.SelectSingleNode(".//span[@class='seed']")
        TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text & s.InnerText & vbCrLf

    Next 
End Sub
```

I can get the "h3", but with the span it gives me an error.. I cannot find any docs on the agility pack and maybe i'm doing wrong method..

How can i select all the span with wanted class in the for each loop (which should already be into the "li" node) ??

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should use the below code. a = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='featuredTorrent']/ul/li/span[@class='wantedclassname']")